# Setting DateTimePicker to Null

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am unable to set the set the Datetimepicker to Null, how can do it. In my project my requirement is to validate the DTPif it is a null, for  that I need to set to Null, The code I am using is:

```
              {
                dateInsert.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateInsert.Text = string.Empty;
               }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a variable and set its value when DateTimePicker value changes

e.g.

```
DateTime? myselectedDate = null;

private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   myselectedDate = DateTimePicker1.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar question but I could not find an answer I liked. However, I did come up with a suitable solution. Set the "ShowCheckBox" property for the datetimepicker to true. This will put a check box next to the date in the box. Then add the following code.

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Checked == false) 
    myVariable = ""; 
else 
    myVariable = dateTimePicker1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like "karthik reddy" noted above you need to use the 'CustomFormat', however to write back a null to the SQL database (for example) your code has to inspect the DateTimePicker when it 'Adds' or 'Updates' a record, so you need at least two pieces of code. Where a) 'dtp_X' is the DateTimePicker control, b) '_NewRecord' is the custom object that is being sent back to the SQL server, c) 'TheDateProperty' is the particular date field or property of the Custom object

```
//Call this when the form Loads 
private void AllowTheDatePickersToBeSetToNothing()      
{
//This let's you set the DatePicker to nothing
dtp_X.CustomFormat = " ";
dtp_X.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

}   

// Call this when Uploading or Adding the record (_NewRecord) to an SQL database    
private void Set_The_Field_Value_based_on_the_CustomFormat_of_the_DateTimePickers()
{
if (dtp_X.CustomFormat == " ")
    {
    //the date should be null
    _NewRecord.TheDateProperty = SqlDateTime.Null;
    }
else
    {
    _NewRecord.TheDateProperty = SqlDateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(dtp_X.Value));
    }

}


//This button resets the Custom Format, so that the user has a way to reset the DateTimePicker Control
private void btn_Reset_dtp_X_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dtp_X.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtp_X.CustomFormat = " ";
}
```